# How to start method from notification action?

Tags: android, methods, notifications, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my main class I have notificationBuilder, which is lanched on button click.

```
        NotificationManager NotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent turnOffIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(NotifiReceiver.turnOffFlash), 0);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb_on)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(getString(R.string.app_name) + "dfddddddggffgf"))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb,
                            getString(R.string.app_name), turnOffIntent);
    NotifyMgr.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

And here is NotifiReceiver.class

```
    package com.AleXMan.torch.standart;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity mna = new MainActivity();
    public static final String turnOffFlash = "com.AleXMan.torch.standart.turnOffFlash";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("test", "recieved");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(turnOffFlash)) {
            mna.toggleFrstFlash();
            Log.i("test", "confirmed");
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

But when i click on this "button" in notification: `.addAction(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb,
                                getString(R.string.app_name), turnOffIntent);`
nothing happens.
Can you tell me what exactly I am doing wrong here?
Thank you very much, for your future help!

Comment: Please post your manifest, showing the `<receiver>` element for your `NotifiReceiver`.

Comment: It's the thing I missed!! Can you write in the anwser, what I need to add to manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, you would need this as a child of your `<application>` element in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="NotifiReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.AleXMan.torch.standart.turnOffFlash" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However, even better would be to replace `new Intent(NotifiReceiver.turnOffFlash)` with `new Intent(this, NotifiReceiver.class)`. Then, you can just have:

```
<receiver android:name="NotifiReceiver"/>
```

for less typing and better security.

Note that this assumes that the `package` in the root `<manifest>` element is `com.AleXMan.torch.standart`.

Comment: @user2186218: Not for the code you have shown here.

Comment: but now, when I press button in notification it crashes, saying:
Process: com.AleXMan.torch.standart, PID: 30894
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.AleXMan.torch.standart.NotifiReceiver: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented

Comment: @user2186218: That's what your receiver does. You can tell that by **reading your own source code** and seeing the `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");` line in it.